# How to implement photoswipe into wordpress custom theme?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, photoswipe

I'm trying to implement photoswipe into my site but I'm not sure how to go about it for a wordpress site..

I'm using acf repeater to display all images in a grid. I'd like to display the photoswipe gallery when an image is clicked.

I've read the documentation for photoswipe, but I don't understand how to use it with a repeater field.

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, sack off photoswipe and use [lightgallery](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/).

Photoswipe is bloated and lightgallery does the same shiz with sweeter options.

If your outputting your repeater field images grid in semantic fashion then this will do the trick...

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/yqcmx8eh/) example.

```js
$('.grid').lightGallery({
  selector: '.lightgallery'
});
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

FIGURE {
  margin: 0;
  width: 25%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

FIGURE A {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

FIGURE A::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

FIGURE A IMG {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/q5Y5RCH.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/q5Y5RCH.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/8HjXPXD.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8HjXPXD.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/vUDcfcy.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vUDcfcy.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/okTDHas.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/okTDHas.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/x7ZYW4i.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/x7ZYW4i.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/EYTCssm.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/EYTCssm.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/3sAFPmL.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3sAFPmL.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/IqLrd0o.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IqLrd0o.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/6JplNl6.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/6JplNl6.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/6X5GKWJ.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/6X5GKWJ.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/SefTwI1.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SefTwI1.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/qBmDrTU.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qBmDrTU.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/x7ZYW4i.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/x7ZYW4i.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/EYTCssm.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/EYTCssm.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/3sAFPmL.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3sAFPmL.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/IqLrd0o.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IqLrd0o.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/6JplNl6.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/6JplNl6.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/6X5GKWJ.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/6X5GKWJ.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/SefTwI1.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SefTwI1.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://i.imgur.com/qBmDrTU.png" class="lightgallery">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qBmDrTU.png" alt="" />
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.7.0/css/lightgallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.7.0/js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery is so "internet explorer"

Comment: @JasomDotnet useful comment 